# Cordova tesseract OCR iOS Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ocr, tesseract

I tried all blogs and answers to do tesseract OCR plugin in Cordova.
But I failed.
I tried jcesarmobile/PhongeapOCRPlugin.

- define plugin interface
- add plugin to the cordova project
- build ios platform in xcode

But link error.

> arm64 not supported.

I tried to rebuild OCR engine. But I can't.
Please give me help who can do iOS Cordova OCR plugin.

Thanks.